# Unity3D Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData causing massive memory leak?

Tags: unity-game-engine, memory-leaks

In one application (`Server`), I am capturing the display:

```c#
public byte[] GetFrame()
{
    int width = Screen.width;
    int height = Screen.height;

    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

    tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
    byte[] bytes = tex.GetRawTextureData();
    Destroy(tex);
    return bytes;
}
```

I send this frame over the network to another application (`Client`), which loads the received frame and puts it as texture on a plane or whatever (some other 3D primitive):

```c#
void DisplayFrame(byte[] frame)
{
    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    texture.LoadRawTextureData(frame);
    texture.Apply();
    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = texture;
    ScreenUpdate = true;
    Destroy(texture);
}
```

This works and the image is displayed as I expected. However, when watching the RAM, I notice that the `Client` RAM goes nuts... over 8GB.

The interesting thing is that if I set `frame = null;` after calling `Destroy(texture);` in `DisplayFrame` on the `Client`, the user only sees a black screen.

I don't understand what is happening here... It's as if the `frame` is staying in memory and each new received frame just increases the memory used.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: There is nothing in your question that proves that `LoadRawTextureData` is the issue. You need to comment the code in your `DisplayFrame` function from bottom to top and run it each time for few seconds then determine what's really causing that issue.

Comment: Yeah, hence the `?` in my question title. I have however gone line-by-line, bottom to top and found that `LoadRawTextureData` is the first line on which I notice the `RAM` being to increase wildly - that is the reason I am asking about it, but I am not sure that it is the real source of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that if I move the `Destroy(texture);` from the bottom of `DisplayFrame(byte[] frame)` to the top of the function, the memory leak is resolved.

It's as if `Destroy` is being blocked because the texture is still being applied to the material when the next iteration comes around. I'm not clear on the issue here, so if someone with more knowledge could chip in, that would be great.